# Phrases to describe firing several shots with a firearm?

Tags: phrase-request

Do you know any phrases to describe firing several shots with a firearm?

I have seen **a burst**, is that natural?

> The gangster fired **a burst** at the cops, then got into his car and speeded off.

Comment: **Burst** is ok. **Volley** and **salvo** are alternatives. If there are a bunch of gangsters opening fire on the cops, it's a **fusillade**.  You may be interested in the following link: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114620/speeded-vs-sped

Comment: A burst implies an automatic weapon! A burst of gunfire from a single person with one weapon. Not a handgun.

Answer (score 2):

Burst is ok. Volley and salvo are alternatives. A volley is, traditionally, a number of shots fired at the same time, e.g. by a firing squad. Fusillade and salvo have the same meaning (Michael Harvey). If there are a bunch of gangsters opening fire on the cops, it's a fusillade. -- Ronald Sole

Note that a “burst” implies the shots are very close together, as from a fully automatic weapon (common in media but rare in real life). If they are a second or more apart, as would be more common with a semi-auto or revolver, I would just say he fired several shots. (StephenS)

Comment: Note that a “burst” implies the shots are very close together, as from a fully automatic weapon (common in media but rare in real life). If they are a second or more apart, as would be more common with a semi-auto or revolver, I would just say he fired several shots.

Comment: Thank you James K. - firm purpose of amendment!

Comment: A volley is, traditionally, a number of shots fired at the same time, e.g. by a firing squad. Fusillade and salvo have the same meaning.